# ConnectAsync trying to use with tcpclient.connected

Tags: vb.net, networking, tcp, timeout

I'm using following code to try to connect to a system, but with handling a timeout. When there is no connection, tcpClient.Connected gives a NullReferenceException after a while

```
    If tcpClient.ConnectAsync(IP, Port).Wait(1000) = False Then
        'Messagebox error
    End If
    If tcpClient.Connected Then
    .....
    End if
```

Stack trace

```
bij System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.get_Connected()
bij directory\System.vb:regel 47
bij System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
bij System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

Comment: When the exception is thrown, is `tcpClient` `Nothing`? If not, what does the stack trace for the exception look like.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.dll for .Connected and tcpClient exists

Comment: So are you saying, without actually saying, that `tcpClient` is not `Nothing`?  In that case, the null reference must be inside the `TcpClient` object somewhere.  That is why I asked for the stack trace that you haven't provided.

Comment: Oh sorry, I updated my OP with stack trace now

Comment: The only thing one can make out of the Stack Trace is that it _seems_ to be the `TcpClient` that is null. However there is a possibility that it's not.